# Minimize $x^*(A+A^*)x$ such that $x^*A^*Ax=1$ and $x^*x=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, normed-spaces, singular-values, qcqp

Given $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, such that it has singular values larger than $1$ and smaller than $1$,

\begin{array}{ll} \underset{x\in\mathbb{C^n}}{\text{minimize}} & x^*(A+A^*)x.\\ \text{subject to} & x^*A^*Ax=1,\\&x^*x=1\end{array}

---

My attempt: I couldn't get anything done for general $A$. Assume $A$ is hermitian, then $A=U\Sigma U^*$, where $U$ is unitary and $\Sigma$ is real diagonal. Let $y=U^*x$, then

\begin{array}{ll} \underset{y\in\mathbb{C^n}}{\text{minimize}} & 2y^*\Sigma y.\\ \text{subject to} & y^*\Sigma^2y=1,\\&y^*y=1\end{array}

Using Lagrange multiplier, we can find: $L(y,\lambda_1,\lambda_2)=2y^*\Sigma y-\lambda_1(y^*\Sigma^2y-1)-\lambda_2(y^*y-1)$. Then

\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial L(y,\lambda_1,\lambda_2)}{\partial y}=4\Sigma y-2\lambda_1\Sigma^2y-2\lambda_2y=0
\end{align}

gives us $y_i=0$ or $\lambda_1\sigma_i^2-2\sigma_i+\lambda_2=0$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n.$

From $\lambda_1\sigma_i^2-2\sigma_i+\lambda_2=0$, we can get $\sigma_i=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-\lambda_1\lambda_2}}{\lambda_1}$, so here I think that if there are many distinct $\sigma_i$'s, then we will get $\sigma_{j_1}=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\lambda_1\lambda_2}}{\lambda_1}$, $\sigma_{j_2}=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\lambda_1\lambda_2}}{\lambda_1}$ (here $j_i$ is any number from $1$ to $n$), and $y_k=0$ for all $k\neq j_2$ and $k\neq j_1$.

From $\sigma_{j_1}=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\lambda_1\lambda_2}}{\lambda_1}$, $\sigma_{j_2}=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\lambda_1\lambda_2}}{\lambda_1}$, we can find that $\lambda_1=\frac{2}{\sigma_{j_1}+\sigma_{j_2}}$ and $\lambda_2=\frac{2\sigma_{j_1}\sigma_{j_2}}{\sigma_{j_1}+\sigma_{j_2}}$.

From this observations, I got impression that for Hermitian $A$, original problem is equivalent to

\begin{array}{ll} \underset{y\in\mathbb{C^2}}{\text{minimize}} & 2y^*\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_{j_1} & \\
 & \sigma_{j_2}
\end{bmatrix} y\quad=\quad\underset{\sigma_{j_1},\sigma_{j_2}}{\text{minimize}} &\sigma_{j_1}\sqrt{\frac{1-\sigma_{j_2}^2}{\sigma_{j_1}^2-\sigma_{j_2}^2}}+\sigma_{j_2}\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_{j_1}^2-1}{\sigma_{j_1}^2-\sigma_{j_2}^2}}\\ \text{subject to} & y^*\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_{j_1} & \\
 & \sigma_{j_2}
\end{bmatrix}^2y=1,&\sigma_{j_1}>1\\&y^*y=1&\sigma_{j_2}<1\end{array}

when $y_1=\sqrt{\frac{1-\sigma_{j_2}^2}{\sigma_{j_1}^2-\sigma_{j_2}^2}}$ and $y_2=\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_{j_1}^2-1}{\sigma_{j_1}^2-\sigma_{j_2}^2}}$.

---

Can you please tell me if the above calculations make sense? Any help on solving (analytically or numerically) the original problem for general $A$ would be appreciated.

Comment: You may well be familiar with this, but just in case, this seems relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient

Comment: When $A$ is general, it boils down to finding $\min x^{\ast} B x$ subject to $x^{\ast}Dx = 1$ and $x^{\ast}x = 1$? You may find literature for QCQP with two constraints.

Comment: @RiverLi thanks, I got semidefinite relaxation of original problem using your tip

Answer (score 2):

Using tip from River Li, I found [the following paper](https://www1.se.cuhk.edu.hk/%7Emanchoso/papers/sdrapp-SPM.pdf).

The original problem is related to QCQPs. Following the paper, we can rewrite the original problem as

\begin{array}{ll} \underset{X\in\mathbb{C^{n\times n}}}{\text{minimize}} & \mathrm{trace}\big((A+A^*)X).\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm{trace}(A^*A)=1,\\&\mathrm{trace}(X)=1,\\&X\geq0,
\\&\mathrm{rank}(X)=1.\end{array}

First we relax the problem by removing rank constraint:

\begin{array}{ll} \underset{X\in\mathbb{C^{n\times n}}}{\text{minimize}} & \mathrm{trace}\big((A+A^*)X).\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm{trace}(A^*A)=1,\\&\mathrm{trace}(X)=1,\\&X\geq0.\end{array}

The latest problem is called semidefinite relaxation (SDR) of original problem and `it can be solved, to any arbitrary accuracy, in numerically reliable and efficient fashion.`

Here is cvx code in Matlab:

```
A=rand(4,4)+i*rand(4,4);
n=length(A);
C=A+A';
A1=A'*A;
A2=eye(n,n);

cvx_begin
variable X(n,n) hermitian
minimize(trace(C*X));
subject to
trace(A1*X)==1;
trace(A2*X)==1;
X == semidefinite(n);
cvx_end
```

After we get an optimal $X$, we can find an optimal $x$ by setting $x=\sqrt{\lambda_{max}}v_{max}$, where $\lambda_{max}$ and $v_{max}$ are largest eigenvalue and corresponding eigenvector of $X$. If the choice is infeasible, we can search for the $x$ which is `nearby` feasible to $\sqrt{\lambda_{max}}v_{max}$.

From simulation it looks like the above method works fine for $x\in\mathbb{R^n},A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. However, for complex matrix case, it has significant error, thus one might be careful in which application it might be used. Worst case computational complexity of SDR of general QCQP is $O(\max\{m,n\}^4n^{0.5}\log(\epsilon^{-1}))$, where $m$ is number of equality constraints and $\epsilon>0$ is a given solution accuracy.

---

EDIT: Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}0.0317 + 0.5409i &  0.2883 - 0.2687i &  0.3905 + 0.4125i\\   0.0636 + 0.9737i & -0.1854 - 0.6985i & -0.3965 + 0.5332i\\  -0.7363 + 0.2243i&   0.3834 + 0.9514i  & 0.6642 - 0.6453i\end{bmatrix}$

Using above cvx code, we get $\mathrm{trace}((A+A^*)X)=-0.1157$ and $X^\star=\begin{bmatrix}0.0760 &  0.2573 &  0.0637\\   0.2573   & 0.8707  & 0.2154 \\   0.0637   & 0.2154  &  0.0533 
\end{bmatrix}$.

But for $X=xx^*$, where $x=\begin{bmatrix}-0.4494 - 0.3663i&-0.3750 + 0.7123i&0.1261 + 0.0000i\end{bmatrix}^T$, we get $\mathrm{trace}((A+A^*)X)=-1.4517.$

Comment: It is nice. I remember there are papers to ensure that there SD relaxation has the same optimal objective value as the original one, for QCQP with two constraints.

Comment: @RiverLi I was searching for the reference that will guarantee that SD relaxation of my problem will have same optimal objective as original one. I found this paper: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S105262340139001X. It is above my level of mathematical understanding, but I tried to pick up important points. Can I say that my problem is considered under Theorem 2.5? I think that Slater's regulariy condition is not satisfied in my case, because we have equality constraints, thus SDR is suboptimal?

Comment: I knew this paper. Not this one.

Comment: @RiverLi I wonder if we can chat regarding this problem?

Comment: Comment here is fine. Have you found new references?

Comment: @RiverLi lots of references. Trying to understand special cases of QCQP. Now reading this one: https://www.jstor.org/stable/25151822?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents

Comment: Looks like slater condition is very important. First I thought that my problem constraints does not satisfy slater condition, but now I think that they do satisfy: there exist $x$ such that $x^*x-1<0$ and $x^*(A^*A-I)x<0$, because eigenvalues of $A^*A$ are spread around 1

Comment: Yes, this is one of the papers I referred to. There are some papers about this topic by these authors.

Comment: @RiverLi thank you very much for the tips, I have solved my problem using this paper: Rank-constrained separable semidefinite programming with applications to optimal beamforming. Indeed, in my problem QCQP optimal and SDR optimal are equal

Comment: Nice to hear that. You are welcome.

Comment: @RiverLi Hi, sorry for disturbing you again, I have one question. In the paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5233822, I want to use Lemma 3.1. For my SDP problem, rank 1 solution exists if both SDP and its corresponding dual problem are  solvable. So after finding dual of the SDP, I need to find out if there always exists real $y_1$ and $y_2$ such that $(A+A^*)-y_1A^*A-y_2I\succeq0$. But for $A=cI$, where $c$ is real, I think we can always choose $c$ in the way that will violate the inequality, so it means that rank-one solution does not exists?

Comment: Once you fix $c$, can you find $y_1, y_2$?

Comment: yes. Can you please have a look into the edited part of my anwer? SDP is not providing optimal solution to original QCQP problem. So I am trying to find an explanation to that.

Comment: You should use X == hermitian_semidefinite(n);

Comment: thanks again, it solved the problem :)

Comment: Nice to hear that. You are welcome.